# using lapply to create ggplot2 histograms with x labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

I am trying to use lapply to generate xlab histogram titles for each histogram in the function

```
plot.labels <- colnames(total_data[27:50])

out1 = lapply(total_data[,27:50], function(x){ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(x, fill=total_data$status,color=total_data$status)) + geom_histogram() + labs(x=plot.labels[x])})

View(plot.labels)
```

plot labels look normal, ex:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz8xU.png) "pct_Myristic"           "pct_Palmitic"           "pct_Palmitelaidic"

I have seen previous answers [Histograms using ggplot2 within loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21511823/histograms-using-ggplot2-within-loop) and [Using lapply to pass labels to ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52212918/using-lapply-to-pass-labels-to-ggplot2) which were helpful for me to create the intial code, and the lapply loop works well to generate all the bivariate histograms w/ ggplot2 since i can't use hist() to seperate the two groups but applying the xlab is giving me trouble. seems that the plot.labels[x] works for some but not all graphs

looks like this, some xlabs are missing
[histograms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz8xU.png)

Comment: well, if some of the plot labels are missing, the first thing I'd do is print `plot.labels` and see if that told me anything interesting.

Comment: I tried that and there were no issues, see updated post

Comment: Ok.  We'll take your word for that.  Of course, if your data were tidy, you could use `geom_hist()` and avoid the loop altogether...

Comment: hi, i would need the loop bc i have 24 histograms

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment about avoiding the loop, and using `mtcars` as OP hasn't provided their input data...

Create a long version of the dataset.

```
library(tidyverse)

longData <- mtcars %>% 
              pivot_longer(
                cols=c(mpg, cyl,  disp,  hp, drat,    wt,  qsec, vs, am, gear),
                names_to="Variable",
                values_to="Value"
              )
```

Now create the plots.

```
longData %>% 
  ggplot() +
    geom_histogram(aes(x=Value, fill=as.factor(carb)), position="identity") +
    facet_wrap(~Variable)
```

[image]